# GetUIkitv2 cannot upload the same file twice

Tags: javascript, css, getuikit

Im using this getuikitv2 upload [component](https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/upload.html) but i had some trouble making it to work properly because if 1 file is uploaded twice the uploader doesnt seems to make any process of uploading and change event wont trigger.

My code is exactly as the page does it work somehow but not when file is uploaded twice. Please help!

Comment: does the file uploaded reach its destination? the problem may lie in your processing file, show code, where you deal with file - the one that you enter in action parameter of the component(probably php)

Comment: im using mea2n (angular2) for this, and i was successfully able to do a a file processing and saves it to the server files. And i was able to figure out the problem, if you upload some file it doesnt reset the selected file therefore whenever you upload the same file again it doesnt trigger the change event because the file doesnt change either. So i managed to reset it and it works perfectly now.